# How does apache storm create its bolt implementations

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-storm

After implementing a very simple apache storm topology in java I ran into a NPE which caused some confusion.

This is basically my main method:

```
TologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("spout", new CustomSpout(true), 4);
final CustomBolt bolt = new CustomBolt();
builder.setBolt("bolt", bolt, 1).shuffleGrouping("spout");

LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
Map conf = new HashMap();
conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKERS, 10);
cluster.submitTopology("test", conf, createTopology());
```

The `CustomBolt` extends `AbstractBasic` class and implements `IRichBolt`. They have these fields:

```
abstract class AbstractBasic {
    A a;
    B b;
} 

CustomBolt extends AbstractBasic implements IRichBolt {
    A anotherA;
    C c;
    CustomBolt() {
        this.anotherA = new A(true);
        this.a = new A(false);
        this.b = new B();
        this.c = new C();
    }
}
```

On the `execute` method of `CustomBolt` there will be some insertions into all classes. However, the fields that are inherited from `AbstractBasic` are not instantiated, but the other ones, the ones that live directly in `CustomBolt`, are...

Does anyone know how a bolt is being contructed and how it's possible that some fields are initialized and some are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When bolts are submitted to the topology, they are [serialized and sent to each worker where they are deserialized](http://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc/backtype/storm/task/IBolt.html). Since `AbstractBasic` does not implement `Serializable`, its fields [will not be serialized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) when `CustomBolt` is serialized.

With the example you give, you should be able to fix your problem by declaring that `AbstractBasic` implements `Serializable`:

```
abstract class AbstractBasic implements Serializable ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how instantiatation works with Bolts but I can find a good reason .
  According to my understanding we run the topology in the distributed environment and to avoid concurrent modifications to the shared variables ( i.e. class level variables inherited from parent classes ) the parent variables could have been set to null in the child classes.